# Из-за чего дата может не попадать в интервал?

Tags: c#

У меня есть `CreatedAtInterval`, который выглядит вот так:

`public OptionalValue<LocalDateTimeInterval> CreatedAtInterval{ get; set; }` и имеет значение:

`"2022-10-21T00:00:00/2022-10-21T23:59:59"`

Я делаю следующее:

```
if ( filter.CreatedAtInterval.HasValue )
     query.Where( x => filter.CreatedAtInterval.Value.Start <= x.CreatedAt
                 && filter.CreatedAtInterval.Value.End >= x.CreatedAt );
```

Ожидая, что мне вернутся данные в промежутке, но это не происходит и мне ничего не возвращается. Вот такой sql формируется:

```
{{"p0":"\"2022-10-21\"","p1":"\"2022-10-21T23:59:59\""}}
"((@p0<=$.CreatedAt) AND (@p1>=$.CreatedAt))"
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

// upd
весь метод, где не работают только даты

```
private ILiteQueryableAsync<VisitorRequestModel> CreateQuery(                                                                    
    ILiteQueryableAsync<VisitorRequestModel> query,                                                                              
    VisitorRequestFilter filter )                                                                                                
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    if ( filter.Visitors?.Values != null )                                                                                       
    {                                                                                                                            
        if ( filter.Visitors.IsNegation )                                                                                        
            query.NotAnyIn( "visitors[*].id",                                                                                    
                filter.Visitors.Values.Select( x => x.ToString() ).ToBsonValues() );                                             
        else                                                                                                                     
            query.AnyIn( "visitors[*].id",                                                                                       
                filter.Visitors.Values.Select( x => x.ToString() ).ToBsonValues() );                                             
    }                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                    
    if ( filter.CreatedAtInterval.HasValue )                                                                                     
        query.Where( x => filter.CreatedAtInterval.Value.Start <= x.CreatedAt                                                    
                    && filter.CreatedAtInterval.Value.End >= x.CreatedAt );                                                      
                                                                                                                                 
    if ( filter.ActivatedAtInterval.HasValue )                                                                                   
        query.Where( x => ( filter.ActivatedAtInterval.Value.Start <= x.ActivatedAt                                              
                    && filter.ActivatedAtInterval.Value.End >= x.ActivatedAt ) );                                                
                                                                                                                                 
    return query;                                                                                                                
}
```

Comment: Возможно это описка, но должно быть `query = query.Where(...)` а не просто `query.Where`.

Comment: @Evk это не описка, но ошибок в написании у меня, как я вижу, нет

Comment: Where (и другие LINQ методы)  не изменяет исходный запрос, он возвращает новый. В данном случае возвращаемое значение игнорируется и по сути эта строка не делает ничего.

Comment: я дополнил вопрос, добавив весь метод, в котором видно, что все фильтры применяются и возвращается query

Comment: Невозможно ответить на этот вопрос. Неизвестно, какие типы/библиотеки используются в коде.

Comment: ну а выборка дат то правильная?

Comment: у вас есть SQL и доступ к БД. Выполните его и поглядите, что возвращается. Может, у вас данных нет в тот период времени

Comment: все возвращается нормально. Мне кажется, в c# есть какие-то особенности в проверке дат в sqlite